# Why Task finishes even in await

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I have a problem in the following code:

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Task newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(MainTask);
    newTask.ContinueWith ((Task someTask) => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Main State=" + someTask.Status.ToString () + " IsFaulted=" + someTask.IsFaulted+" isComplete="+someTask.IsCompleted);
    });
    while (true) 
    {

    }
}

static async Task MainTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine ("MainStarted!");
    Task someTask = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("SleepStarted!");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine ("SleepEnded!");
    });
    await someTask;
    Console.WriteLine ("Waiting Ended!!");
    throw new Exception ("CustomException!");
    Console.WriteLine ("NeverReaches here!!");
}
```

I just want to get Exception from new started task `MainTask`. But the result was not what I was expected.

```
MainStarted!
Main State = RanToCompletion IsFaulted = False isComplete = True
SleepStarted!
SleepEnded!
Waiting Ended!!
```

As you can see the result, task finishes before "Waiting Ended!!" console log.
I don't have a clue that why `MainTask` ended even if in `MainTask` has `await` command inside?
Did I missed something?

Comment: Any reason why you can't do `MainTask().ContinueWith(...)` directly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` [does not understand async delegates](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) so you need to use `Task.Run` in this case and the exception should flow through.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(MainTask);
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MainTask);
```

which ignores the returned task from `MainTask` and the exception just gets swallowed.

See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) for more details.

Try using `Task.Run` instead and you'll get your exception:

```
void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task newTask = Task.Run(MainTask);
    newTask.ContinueWith((Task someTask) =>
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Main State=" + someTask.Status.ToString() + " IsFaulted=" + someTask.IsFaulted + " isComplete=" + someTask.IsCompleted);
   });
    while (true)
    {

    }
}

static async Task MainTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine("MainStarted!");
    Task someTask = Task.Run(() =>
   {
       Console.WriteLine("SleepStarted!");
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
       Console.WriteLine("SleepEnded!");
   });
    await someTask;
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting Ended!!");
    throw new Exception("CustomException!");
    Console.WriteLine("NeverReaches here!!");
}
```

Comment: @MickyDuncan, To rephrase that: "TaskFactory.StartNew doesn’t support async-aware delegates. Task.Run does." See this [blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html).

Comment: Perhaps I should say it does not understand async delegates. See http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Answer (score 6):

There's great answers here, but I'd like to point out the obvious - the `Task.Factory.StartNew` is completely redundant, unnecessary and used wrong.

If you replace

```
Task newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(MainTask);
```

with

```
Task newTask = MainTask();
```

You'll get exactly the behaviour you expect, without wasting yet another threadpool thread just to start *another* threadpool thread. In fact, if you wanted to rewrite your example to be more idiomatic, you'd use something like this:

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    var task = 
      MainTask()
      .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Main State={0}", t.Status));

    task.Wait();
}

static async Task MainTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine ("MainStarted!");

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    Console.WriteLine ("Waiting Ended!!");

    throw new Exception ("CustomException!");

    Console.WriteLine ("NeverReaches here!!");
}
```

This code only uses a thread pool thread for the code after the delay, and rethrows the exception on the `task.Wait()` call - you might want to do something else, of course.

As a side-note, even if you don't want to explicitly wait for the task to complete, you shouldn't use `while (true) {}` to prevent the application from terminating - a simple `Console.ReadLine()` will work just as well, and isn't going to push one of your CPU cores to 100% utilization :)

Answer (score 1):

I modified your problem here to catch the exceptions.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoFoo();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }



    static async void DoFoo()
    {
        try
        {
            await Foo();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //This is where you can catch your exception
        }
    }




    static async Task Foo()
    {

        await MainTask().ContinueWith((Task someTask) =>
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Main State=" + someTask.Status.ToString() + " IsFaulted=" + someTask.IsFaulted + " isComplete=" + someTask.IsCompleted);

        }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);

    }

    static async Task MainTask()
    {


        Console.WriteLine("MainStarted!");
        Task someTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SleepStarted!");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("SleepEnded!");
        });
        await someTask;
        throw new Exception("CustomException!");

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting Ended!!");


    }
```

you should  use `TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted` which means that the continue with task will only execute if the parent task did not had any exceptions.